# How read the different's field row by using CSV in Go?

Tags: csv, go

I am want to read the data from a `csv` file. but the file have different field inside at the end of the file. I do also want to extract those line, when meet the `ErrFieldCount`. How can i do that.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "errors"
)

func main() {
    in := `first_name,last_name,username
"Rob","Pike",rob
Ken,Thompson,ken
"Robert","Griesemer"
`
    r := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(in))

    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        
        if err != nil {
            if errors.Is(err, csv.ErrFieldCount) {
                // fmt.Println("#", differentRow")
               log.Fatal("wrong fields")
               //TODO I want to pick it up here
            }else{
               log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(record)
    }
}
```

My expect output:

```
[first_name last_name username]
[Rob Pike rob]
[Ken Thompson ken]
# "Robert","Griesemer".   <---- my expect line ...
2009/11/10 23:00:00 wrong fields
```

Comment: `go doc encoding/csv.Reader.FieldsPerRecord` . Always read the whole documentation for the types and packages you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `csv.ErrFieldCount` is returned, you still get the (parsed) line in your `record` variable, so just print that. This is documented at [`Reader.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader.Read):

> f the record has an unexpected number of fields, Read returns the record along with the error ErrFieldCount.

And don't use [`log.Fatal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal) to print a message as that terminates your app.

```
if err != nil {
    if errors.Is(err, csv.ErrFieldCount) {
        fmt.Println("#", record)
        log.Println("wrong fields")
    } else {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    continue
}
```

With this change the output is what you wish for:

```
[first_name last_name username]
[Rob Pike rob]
[Ken Thompson ken]
# [Robert Griesemer]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 wrong fields
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pyr43cOD9DX).

Comment: It works now. But what if I want to read it at one time with `ReadAll`, is it possible to catch the error?

Comment: @FrankAK Nope, it's not possible with `ReadAll()` as it stops when such error is encountered, and it does not return successfully read lines either.